# Does including a call to jquery in rmarkdown cause issues with packages?

Tags: jquery, r, r-markdown, dt

I am trying to include a `DT::datatable` in an HTML document I'm creating with `rmarkdown` and I'm experiencing an issue that seems to be happening to other people ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438664/r-rmarkdownrender-looses-js-dependencies-of-dtdatatable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343241/rmarkdown-and-dt-result-do-not-render)).

Here is my yaml at the beginning of the file:

```
---
title: ''
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: NULL
    css: main.css
    includes:
      in_header: js.txt
---
```

Here is the contents of js.txt:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Is something in either my yaml or my js.txt file causing `DT::datatable` to not render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, it can cause an issue. I don't know if it's just the version of jquery that was being included, or if it was the inclusion of a javascript file in my header through the yaml. Either way, by removing the `includes` portion of the yaml and moving my call to my javascript `main.js` to the body of my `rmarkdown` document, I was able to resolve the issue. The yaml now looks like the following:

```
title: ''
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: NULL
    css: main.css
```

And `<script src="main.js"></script>` now just resides in my .Rmd file. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.